# Turn ListA of objects into ListA of lists that contain these objects by attribute value

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, sql-server, group-by

Let's say I have the following orders from the database, all in a list. All these orders map to 1 user.

```
Order1 ----- Confirmed  ---- 09/01/2022
Order1 ----- Dispatched ---- 10/01/2022
Order1 ----- Delivered  ---- 11/01/2022
Order2 ----- Confirmed  ---- 10/01/2022
Order2 ----- Dispatched ---- 11/01/2022
```

I receive these on .net c# to send them to the front end. Each order is an object like the following:

```
new {OrderID,Status,StatusDate}
```

And the list looks something like this:

```
[{},{},{},{},{}]
```

With each "{}" being one of the records above. I want to turn that list of order progress records into a list of lists, where each list contains the progress records of 1 order. So the list will look like this:

```
[[Order1 progress],[Order2 progress]]
```

Each order progress list will contain the exact records written above but only the records that have the same OrderID. Then I want to loop through that final list on my frontend to display on the user's page.

I have seen some solutions with Python(with a groupby import) but none that use C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LINQ's `GroupBy` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0):

```
List<Order> listOfOrders = LoadOrders();

List<List<Order>> groupedListOfOrders = listOfOrders
    .GroupBy(o => o.OrderID, (_, orders) => orders.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple LINQ method and foreach loop.

```
List<Order> data = <your order data list>
```

output list of list

```
List<List<Order>> OrderList = new List<List<Order>>();

foreach (var order in data.Select(t => t.OrderId).Distinct())
 {
  OrderList.Add((List<Order>)data.Where(o => o.OrderId == order));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know whether this answer is more performant to the answer from @Richard ?

Comment: @CodingGoneWrong This version would iterate over the source list `N+1` times - once to get the distinct list of order IDs, and once for each order ID - whereas the `GroupBy` option will only iterate once. However, this code will *actually* throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime, since the value returned from `.Where(...)` is not a `List<Order>`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I fully understand and it makes sense! Thank you very much to both of you for the help and explanations! Have a good one!